# What is the best way to store market data for Algorithmic Trading setup?

Tags: sql, database, file, nosql, algorithmic-trading

I am making an Algorithmic Trading setup for trades automation. Currently, I have a broker API which helps me get historical data for all stocks that I'm interested in.

I am wondering how to store all the data, whether in a file system or database (SQL based or NoSQL). Data comes through REST API if thats relevant.

My use case here would be to query historical data to make trading decisions in live market. I would also have to develop a backtesting framework that will query Historical Data to check performance of strategy historically.

I am looking at a frequency of 5 mins - 1 hr candles and mostly Intraday trading strategies. Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question is primarily opinion based, so off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I certainly think there is a large technical view when deciding on how to store data, because query time is essential while having algorithms trading your own money.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: The first trial involved writing rules on Excel and using it to fetch data from other CSV and trust me it was taking so long. That's when I dropped the Excel idea all together. Although I am not sure how fast the same process will be in Java/Python.

Answer (score 5):

As you say, there are many options and as STLDeveloper says this is kind of off topic since it is opinion based... anyway...

A simple strategy which I used in my own Python back-testing engine is to use Python Pandas `DataFrame` objects, and save/load to disk in an HD5 file using `to_hdf()` and `read_hdf()`. The primary advantage (for me) of HD5 is that it loads/saves far more quickly than CSV.

Using the above approach I easily manage several years of 1 minute data for back testing purposes, and data access certainly is not my performance bottleneck.

You will need to determine for yourself if your chosen data management approach is fast enough for live trading, but in general I think if your strategy is based on 5-min candles then any reasonable database approach is going to be sufficiently performant for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the lead. I will try HD5 and as its something that you are already using, I am sure it will be helpful for me as well.

Comment: I benchmarked HDF and CSV file and I found HDF to be far slower. Using pandas CSV is not the right approach. Just using the CSV module is speedy enough and a lot more usable. I don't even understand why people recommend other formats when CSV and file hierarchy does the job..